# NoSuchMethodError when declaring a variable

Tags: scala, exception

I'm running into a weird error when using Spark and Scala. I have a piece of code that declares a variable:

```
var offset = 0
```

This causes the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.IntRef.create(I)Lscala/runtime/IntRef;
   at my.package.MyClass$class.myMethod(MyClass.scala:5)
   ...
```

And it points directly at the variable declaration. I am using Scala 2.11.2. Compiling works. This is a runtime error. I do not get any dependency/version mismatch warnings when running `sbt package` either.

Comment: This is almost certainly a scala version mismatch. Comparing the definition of `IntRef` in v2.10 and v2.11, you can see that `create` was only introduced in the latter version (see https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.4/src/library/scala/runtime/IntRef.java and https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.0/src/library/scala/runtime/IntRef.java). You can bet that some of your dependencies was compiled against a scala version < 2.11.0. You muight want to try sbt-dependency-graph (https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) to check your transitive dependencies.

Comment: Yeah you were right Règis. I changed my Scala version to 2.10.4 and it started working as expected. You can put your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is almost certainly a scala version mismatch. 
Comparing the definition of IntRef in v2.10 and v2.11, you can see that `create` was only introduced in the latter version (see https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.4/src/library/scala/runtime/IntRef.java and https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.0/src/library/scala/runtime/IntRef.java). 
You can bet that some of your dependencies was compiled against a scala version < 2.11.0.
You might want to try sbt-dependency-graph (https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) to check your transitive dependencies.