# Error with variable declaration - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.IntRef.create(I)Lscala/runtime/IntRef; - scala version mismatch

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am working with a Spark/Scala application on intelliJ with Maven. I am trying to write a file and after the writing is complete, I am trying to read it line by line and increment a variable named `count` depending on a condition. Here is my code:

```
val writer: BufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.csv"))
/* Logic
    for
   writing 
  the file
*/
writer.close()

var count = 0
val bufferedSource = Source.fromFile("test.csv")

for(line <- bufferedSource.getLines()){
    count = count+1
    line.split(",").foreach(x => {if(x.toString == "1") count = count+1})
}

bufferedSource.close()
```

When I run the above code, it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.IntRef.create(I)Lscala/runtime/IntRef;
```

It is throwing the error at the variable declaration statement:  `var count = 0`

I searched for this error online and found the reason to be `scala version mismatch`, as pointed out here: [NoSuchMethodError when declaring a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925375/nosuchmethoderror-when-declaring-a-variable)

Initially, I had my project SDK setup to `2.10.6`. That's the default version I use for my projects. I didn't mention any scala language dependency in my pom.xml. And when I run the `mvn -U package` command for building the jar, I get the following messages:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building project
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ IPscan ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\zkh9xcl\workspace\IPscan\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) @ IPscan ---
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.11.7
[WARNING]  com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0 requires scala version: 2.11.7
[WARNING]  com.twitter:chill_2.10:0.5.0 requires scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ IPscan ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ IPscan ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\zkh9xcl\workspace\IPscan\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:testCompile (scala-test-compile) @ IPscan ---
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.11.7
[WARNING]  com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0 requires scala version: 2.11.7
[WARNING]  com.twitter:chill_2.10:0.5.0 requires scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ IPscan ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ IPscan ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ IPscan ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.4.1:shade (default) @ IPscan ---
[INFO] Including com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:jar:1.4.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.univocity:univocity-parsers:jar:1.5.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Skipping pom dependency org.jodd:jodd:pom:3.4.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.threeten:threetenbp:jar:1.3.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Attaching shaded artifact.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.054 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-26T11:18:39-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 38M/663M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It is throwing a warning saying: `[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!`

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>project</groupId>
  <artifactId></artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>IPscan</name>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>scala-compile-first</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>

          <execution>
            <id>scala-test-compile</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <relocations>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>org.apache.http</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>org.shaded.apache.http</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
              </relocations>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>

                </filter>
              </filters>
              <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
              <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
            </configuration>

          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>   
  </build>    
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-csv_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jodd/jodd -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jodd</groupId>
      <artifactId>jodd</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.threeten/threetenbp -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
      <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am new to maven, please excuse me if there is a probelm with my `pom.xml`.

I am not sure why there are multiple versions of scala libraries included in the jar. I actually changed the java version to `2.11.7` and then to `2.10.4` in the global libraries of the project in intelliJ, but it gives a problem saying `Library scala-sdk-2.10.4 is not used [Fix]`. I am pretty sure I added `2.10.4` to the list of dependencies in intelliJ. No matter what I do, I still get the `multiple scala versions` warning when I build the jar and the `noSuchMethodError` still persists. Looks like I am missing something.

What is causing the error? And what is the best way to overcome this and avoid it in the future? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

**P.S:** I am using Spark 1.6 and I can't upgrade to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple case of dependency mismatch. My guess is that it is because of the `spark-csv` package by `com.databricks`. Can you change the version to `2.10` and try again.

Let me know if this helped. Cheers.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I changed `spark-csv_2.11` to `spark-csv_2.10` and now I get these warnings: `[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.10.5
[WARNING]  com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0 requires scala version: 2.10.5 
[WARNING]  com.twitter:chill_2.10:0.5.0 requires scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!`  and the error still persists.

Comment: can you confirm that the scala sdk version in intellij is 2.10?

Comment: and also comment out the repositories and pluginRepositories section of pom

Comment: Yes, i have set the sdk to be `2.10.4` in the global libraries. as you can see in my above comment, the `spark-csv_2.10` is asking for scala version `2.10.5` now. I also tried changing the scala version in the IDE to `2.10.5`. I also see `2.10.5` being included in the dependencies. I am not sure where multiple versions of scala are coming from.

Comment: commented out the repositories. Still the same warnings and error. I am building the jar from the maven console and not from IDE itself, if that helps troubleshoot the error..